# Stop device connected as host charging connected device

Tags: charging, 4.4-kitkat, usb-host-mode

I am connecting a Nexus 10 to an Arduino board in host mode. The Arduino board has its own power supply, but is still drawing power from the tablet. [This](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?PHPSESSID=nqq2fov9pkmke1q6l680kabni5&topic=209354.0) post suggests that this may happen if the consumption is less than 6.6v

Is there a way of telling the tablet to not charge the Arduino board?

Comment: Are you asking about code to put in some of your application ("programatically"), or a general setting?

Comment: @Izzy For any way of achieving it, perhaps a hack at at the Linux level? Have removed the word programatically from the question

Comment: OK, just wanted to make sure it's not an off-topic development question :) You might wish to take a look at [these questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=usb+host+charging+is%3Aquestion) and their answers. With some luck they at least give you a pointer. Don't forget to keep us updated here :)